# Closure with D3.Transition.Each Callback

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a D3.js animation that does the following:

1. Rectangle starts with 0 width and expands to the right
2. Rectangle then contracts from the left
3. Repeat forever

I have created a simple animation using a recursive immediate function as demostrated in this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1125997

```
function Sweep() {
    var rect = d3.select(this);
    (function repeat() {
        rect = rect.transition()
        .attr("x", function(){ return rect.attr("width") < width ? 0 : width; })
        .attr("width", function () { return rect.attr("width") < width ? width : 0; })
        .each("end", function () {
            d3.select(this).attr("x", 0);            
            repeat();
            });
    })();
}
```

The recursion seems to be working correctly, however the line of code that resets x to 0 does not seem to work. I suspect this is a closure related issue, where the context inside the "end" callback is not what I expect.

The full code can be viewed here.
http://jsfiddle.net/p3RZ7/

You will see that the first two iterations work, but nothing beyond that is visible because the x attribute is not reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for what you want to do is actually much easier than you think. You can do everything in your `Sweep` function, including setting the `x` attribute to 0:

```
function Sweep() {
  d3.select(this).attr("x", 0)
    .transition().ease("linear").duration(sweepDuration)
    .attr("x", function(){ return d3.select(this).attr("width") < width ? 0 : width; })
    .attr("width", function () { return d3.select(this).attr("width") < width ? width : 0; })
    .each("end", Sweep);
}
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p3RZ7/1/).

Comment: Thank you! This is a much simpler solution.

From a closure perspective, why didn't the previous code work?